# iterate char** why does this work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, glib

I picked up a this piece of code I copy past to my program. This seems to be a new way to me to iterate through char**:

```
char** vArray;          // The array containing values

// Go throught properties
if(szKey == "KeyMgmt")
{
    vArray = (char**)g_value_get_boxed((GValue*)value);
    for( ; vArray && *vArray ; vArray++)  // Why does this work ?!
        pWpaKey->addKeyMgmt(std::string(*vArray));
}
else if(szKey == "Pairwise")
{
    // ...
}
```

It looks like to work like a charm but I don't understant why! vArray is Supposed to contain an adress right? And *vArray the "string" value. So why when I "AND" an address with its value this give me an equality?

Comment: As a hint: `&&` is a logical AND, and `&` is a binary AND.

Comment: C tag replaced with C++. There is no `::` in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop condition is

```
vArray && *vArray
```

This is basically shorthand for

```
(vArray != 0) && (*vArray != 0)
```

which is true if the `char**` pointer is non-null and points to a `char*` which is non-null.

Comment: mmm nice I didn't assume that the last value for *vArray was 0! So the first parameter (vArray) is just sanity check ... Thanks this is much more clear!

Comment: Not just a sanity check. If `g_value_get_boxed()` returns `NULL`, and that check isn't in, then BAM! Segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5):

`vArray && *vArray` is equivalent to `(vArray != NULL) && (*vArray != NULL)`

It's first checking that the pointer `vArray` isn't `NULL` and, assuming it is not `NULL`, checking that the pointer it points to isn't `NULL`.